# SQL SELECT ID WHERE rows with the same ID have different Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I need some help creating a SQL statement across rows.

```
    SELECT SZ.Stammindex AS ID, S.sEbene1, S.sEbene2, S.sEbene3
    FROM SuchbaumZuordnung SZ 
    LEFT JOIN Suchbaum S 
    ON SZ.gSuchbaumID = S.gID
    WHERE (S.sEbene1 IN ('Test1') 
    AND (S.sEbene2 IN ('Test2') OR S.sEbene2 IS NULL) 
    AND S.sEbene3 IS NULL)
```

[image: This is what I got so far]

As you can see in the screenshot, I selected ID=10004 and ID=10005. But actually I only want ID=10005 to show up. I am trying to filter across Rows as already mentioned.

My goal is to get all the IDs, where all the conditions are connected with "AND", something like this:

```
WHERE (sEbene1 IN ('Test1') 
       AND (sEbene2 IN ('Test2') *AND* sEbene2 IS NULL) 
       AND sEbene3 IS NULL)
```

But this will return nothing.

*Edit*

[image: Table Suchbaum structure]

[image: Table SuchbaumZuorndung structure]

I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: How can `sEbene2` be BOTH `'Test2'` and `NULL` in the same row?  Also sample data, desired results and a database tag would help.  You have two tables and it is quite unclear where the columns are coming from.

Comment: This is how the TreeView gets saved. The meaning of `sEbende2` with the value`Test2` in one row and in the other one `Null` is, that the TreeView has the ID under `Test1 > Test2` and `Test1`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want:

```
SELECT SZ.Stammindex AS ID
FROM SuchbaumZuordnung SZ 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Suchbaum S
              WHERE SZ.gSuchbaumID = S.gID AND
                    S.sEbene1 IN ('Test1') AND
                    sEbene2 IN ('Test2')
             ) AND
       EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Suchbaum S
              WHERE SZ.gSuchbaumID = S.gID AND
                    S.sEbene2 IS NULL AND
                    S.sEbene3 IS NULL
             );
```

This is looking for two *different* rows in `Suchbaum`, each one matching one of the conditions.

Comment: As already written under Larnu's comment section, there can be multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you only have 3 columns you want to check different rows, it seems like this would be easily serviced with a CTE and a Windowed `COUNT`:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT SZ.Stammindex AS ID,
           S.sEbene1, --Guessed the table alias
           S.sEbene2, --Guessed the table alias
           S.sEbene3, --Guessed the table alias
           COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(ISNULL(S.S.sEbene1,'-'),ISNULL(S.sEbene2,'-'),ISNULL(S.sEbene3,'-'))) OVER (PARTITION BY SZ.Stammindex) AS DistinctRows
    FROM SuchbaumZuordnung SZ 
         LEFT JOIN Suchbaum S ON SZ.gSuchbaumID = S.gID) --This was missing the ON in your sample
SELECT C.Stammindex,
       C.sEbene1,
       C.sEbene2,
       C.sEbene3
FROM CTE C
WHERE C.DistinctRows > 1;
```

If it's purely where an ID has more than 1 rows (which could be identical) then you can just use `COUNT`:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT SZ.Stammindex AS ID,
           S.sEbene1, --Guessed the table alias
           S.sEbene2, --Guessed the table alias
           S.sEbene3, --Guessed the table alias
           COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY SZ.Stammindex) AS [Rows]
    FROM SuchbaumZuordnung SZ 
         LEFT JOIN Suchbaum S ON SZ.gSuchbaumID = S.gID)
SELECT C.Stammindex,
       C.sEbene1,
       C.sEbene2,
       C.sEbene3
FROM CTE C
WHERE C.[Rows] > 1;
```

Comment: My Table has up to 10 Columns so from sEbene1 up to sEbene10 and the ID can show up multiple times

Comment: *"up to 10 columns?"* So it varies? That seems odd; a table's design *should* be pretty static. The answer here is based on the sample we have, which only has 4 columns, not 10. You should, however, easily be able to expand this for more columns; if you can't that would mean you don't understand the answer and that's what your comments should be about

Comment: No its static with 10 columns. I am only showing the first three columns, because the others are filled with NULL.